# Moving an uploaded file in php

Tags: php

I am trying to replace the uploaded file into a location.

My code is:

```
if (isset($_FILES['image']['name']))       
{
    $saveto = 'img/$user.jpg';      //$user would be the name of the current user.
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $saveto);
}
```

I'm getting this error,

```
Warning: move_uploaded_file(img/$user.jpg): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/profile.php on line 33
```

Although the permissions are set, `sudo chmod 777`. It is still giving me this error, what is the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

First, you change `$saveto = 'img/$user.jpg';` to `$saveto = "img/$user.jpg";`. In PHP declaring strings with `'` and `"` have different behaviours. With `'` it won't fetch the value of `$user` into the string, instead it will write `$user` literally.

But this is not the error. The error is that you don't have permission to create the file in the directory `/img/`. Make sure you have set the right permissions in this folder.

Or maybe it's because `$` isn't a valid symbol for file name in Linux, I'm not sure about that though.